# JQuery change text on mouse over and return to original on mouseout

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, mouseover, mouseout

I have this code, it works on mouseover but when *mouse out* off the **a** element it does not show the original text in **p**

```
$("a.brieflink").bind("mouseover", function() {
    $("div#brieftext").text($(this).data("text"));
});
$("a.brieflink").bind("mouseout", function() {
    $("brieftext").hide($(this).data("text"));
});

<a href="1.html" class="brieflink" data-src="article.jpg" data-text="text1">Brief 1</a>
<a href="2.html" class="brieflink" data-src="article.jpg" data-text="text2">Brief 2</a>
<a href="3.html" class="brieflink" data-src="article.jpg" data-text="text3">Brief 3</a>

<div id="brieftext"><p>Original text</p></div>
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that when you use `$("div#brieftext").text($(this).data("text"))` to set the text of `brieftext`,you have clear its original content,so if you want to show the original content again,you need to invoke `html()` to set it manually

```js
$("a.brieflink").bind("mouseover", function() {
    $("#brieftext").text($(this).data("text"));
});
$("a.brieflink").bind("mouseout", function() {
    $("#brieftext").html("<p>Original text</p>");//set the content manaully
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="1.html" class="brieflink" data-src="article.jpg" data-text="text1">Brief 1</a>
<a href="2.html" class="brieflink" data-src="article.jpg" data-text="text2">Brief 2</a>
<a href="3.html" class="brieflink" data-src="article.jpg" data-text="text3">Brief 3</a>

<div id="brieftext"><p>Original text</p></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!